# How to move a column in a table by its header value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want the 'adult' column moved to the last position (on the right) in the table, but the table is interactive, the number of columns is not fixed, and sometimes, there will be no 'adult' column.

Please help

Here's the table:

```css
table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<table class="tableizer-table">
 <thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th></th><th>adult</th><th>embryo</th><th>lava</th><th>pupa</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>AAEL006466-RA</td><td>ns</td><td>ns</td><td>**</td><td>ns</td></tr>
  <tr><td>AAEL006466-S2</td><td>***</td><td>ns</td><td>ns</td><td>ns</td></tr>
  <tr><td>AAEL006466-S4</td><td>***</td><td>ns</td><td>*</td><td>ns</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you like to have a method in javascript to remove the first column if it contains adult?

Comment: What do you mean by "go to the back"? Are you trying to move the table's first column to the right to become the last column, but only if the header is "Adult"? Is any of that CSS at all relevant to what you are asking?

Comment: yes, i want to move the 'adult' to the right to become the last column, can CSS do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will reorder the columns so that the 'adult' column is put last (if it is present in any position in the table).

It does presume that there is AT MOST only one column headed 'adult' (having no 'adult' column is fine though):

```js
$(function() {

  function reorderTable() {

    var adultCol;
    var $headerCells = $(".tableizer-firstrow").children();
    
    $headerCells.each(function(idx, el) {
       var title = (el.textContent || el.innerText || "").toLowerCase();
       if (title === 'adult') adultCol = idx;       
    });
    
    if (adultCol) { // adult column is present
      $(".tableizer-table tr").each(function(idx, el) {
        $(this).append($(this).children().eq(adultCol));
      });
    }
  };

  reorderTable();
  
});
```

```css
table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="tableizer-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
      <th></th>
      <th>adult</th>
      <th>embryo</th>
      <th>lava</th>
      <th>pupa</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAEL006466-RA</td>
      <td>ns</td>
      <td>ns</td>
      <td>**</td>
      <td>ns</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAEL006466-S2</td>
      <td>***</td>
      <td>ns</td>
      <td>ns</td>
      <td>ns</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAEL006466-S4</td>
      <td>***</td>
      <td>ns</td>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>ns</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT** Here's an explanation of how it works...

```
$(function() {  // this waits for DOM to load fully before executing

  function reorderTable() {

    var adultCol; // this will be the column number that has the 'adult' header
    var $headerCells = $(".tableizer-firstrow").children(); // gets the collection of <th> cells

    $headerCells.each(function(idx, el) { // runs a function on each <th> cell

       // The following is equivalent to writing $(el).text().toLowerCase() -
       // to get the inner text so that we can compare it to our search phrase.
       // But it is more entertaining to write and will run faster than jQuery's fn.
       // It's job is to handle differences between browsers, and to ignore case for the comparison later
       var title = (el.textContent || el.innerText || "").toLowerCase(); 
       if (title === 'adult') adultCol = idx; // if we have a match, remember the column #

    });

    if (adultCol) { // run only if we found the `adult` column index (i.e. it is not null or undefined)
      $(".tableizer-table tr").each(function() { // loop over EVERY table row (so both header and body)
        // `this` is the current row, and $(this).append(...) will move an element (cell) 
        // to the last position in that row.
        // the inner part says give me the nth cell to move. 
        // The nth cell being the 'adult' column.
        $(this).append($(this).children().eq(adultCol)); 
      });
    }
  };

  reorderTable(); // execute the above function

});
```

Comment: Just added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```js
$(function() {
 let firstColumnHeader;
 let findPosToMove = $("table").find('tr')[0].cells.length - 2;
 jQuery.each($("table tr"), function(index, value) {
  if(index === 0){
   firstColumnHeader = ($(this).children(":eq(1)")[index].innerText);
  }
  if(firstColumnHeader == 'adult'){
   for(var i = 0; i < findPosToMove; i++){
    $(this).children(":eq(1)").before($(this).children(":eq("+(findPosToMove+1)+")"));
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```css
table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableizer-table">
  <thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th></th><th>adult</th><th>embryo</th><th>lava</th><th>pupa</th></tr></thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>AAEL006466-RA</td><td>ns</td><td>ns</td><td>**</td><td>ns</td></tr>
    <tr><td>AAEL006466-S2</td><td>***</td><td>ns</td><td>ns</td><td>ns</td></tr>
    <tr><td>AAEL006466-S4</td><td>***</td><td>ns</td><td>*</td><td>ns</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The question wasn't tagged with "jQuery". Also, wouldn't `$(this).children(":eq(4)").after($(this).children(":eq(1)"));` do each row in one line, rather than calling `.before()` three times?

Comment: oh, i should add jQuery, but since it is a interactive table, the number of columns is not fixed, and it might not contain the 'adult' column, so seems can not use :eq4,

Comment: did some modification in the script if there is no such 'adult' column is present in the table.